# How to use vue-router in child component only?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am new to vuejs and have some questions when using it.
I create a root view, with 2 child component in it, the rootview.vue file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="rootView">
    <calendar-top-view></calendar-top-view>
    <calendar-bottom-view></calendar-bottom-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import calendarTopView from './calendarTopView.vue'
  import calendarBottomView from './calendarBottomView.vue'
  export default {
  components: {
    'calendar-top-view': calendarTopView,
    'calendar-bottom-view': calendarBottomView
  }
}
</script>
```

and in calendar-bottom-view component, I need to use vue-router to help switch between to child components: calendarView and agendaView. So I decide to add vue-router just in my calendar-bottom-vue component, and the code looks like below:

```
<template>
  <div id='mainRightDiv'>
    <div id='calendarToolboxDiv'>
      <a v-link='{ path: "/calenarView"}'></a>
      <a v-link='{ path: "/agendaView"}'></a>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import calendarView from './calendarView.vue'
  import agendaView from './agendaView.vue'
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
  Vue.use(VueRouter)
  let App = Vue.extend({})
  let router = new VueRouter()
  router.map({
    '/calendarView': {
      component: calendarView
    },
    '/agendaView': {
      component: agendaView
    }
  })
  export default {
    ready: function () {
      router.go({ path: '/calendarView'})
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I intend to do is to let the router to render calendarView first when the component is initialized. But when I run this page, I got error message like

'router-view> can only be used inside a router-enabled app.'

I checked the official spec of vue-router and found in its demo code, vue-router was used in entry js of the demo app, not found any use in any child component.

So I wonder, how can I use vue-router in one of my child component, instead of root?

Comment: I find out that dynamic components is enough for what I need. No need vue-router. But I still wonder how to do with vue-router.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use Browserify with Vueify, you create `.js` file, which should have structure:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var Router = require('vue-router');
Vue.use(Router);
Vue.config.debug = true;
//any other npm packages

import Alert from './components/Alert.vue';
import SubVue1 from './pages/Subvue1.vue';
import SubVue2 from './pages/Subvue2.vue';
import Bar from './pages/Bar.vue';
import Baz from './pages/Baz.vue';

var App = Vue.extend({
    data: function () {
        return {
            //any ViewModel data
        }
    },
    components: {Alert}
});

var router = new Router();
router.map({
    // Not found handler
    '*': {
        component: {
            template: '<div class="text-align:center">' +
            '<h1>Not Found</h1>' +
            '</div>'
        }
    },
    '/sub1': {
        name: 'subvue1',
        component: SubVue1
    },
    '/sub2': {
        name: 'subvue2',
        component: SubVue2
        // add a subRoutes map under /foo
        subRoutes: {
             '/bar': {
               // Bar will be rendered inside Foo's <router-view>
               // when /foo/bar is matched
               component: Bar
             },
             '/baz': {
                // Same for Baz, but only when /foo/baz is matched
                component: Baz
             }
        }
   }
});

router.start(App, 'body'); // #app,.start -as you wish
```

Note that I use vue-router in the root parent `.js` file.So basically when you enter **/sub1**, then Subvue1.vue is loaded. Pay attention to **subroutes** (calendarView and agendaView switch). Every SubVue,Bar,Baz should have structure:

```
<template>
  <router-view><router-view> //For Subvue2 subroute
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['parentProperty'],
        data: function () {// data}
        methods:{}
    }
<style></style>
```

Read [Vue Router](http://router.vuejs.org/en/nested.html) docs for more info.

Comment: hi, @Dandruff, I use webpack as bundle, and use vue-loader to load my .vue file. With the help of babel, it works perfectly with ES6. What you said above is almost the same in official tutorial for vue-router, but it does not meet my satisfaction.

Comment: I have never used webpack, so I can't suggest other solutions. As well never tried router in a component, but logically it should work, because it's JS basically.